# Filing taxes in Canada but only worked in the United States

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada

My boyfriends has native status and lives in Canada, however works in the United States. He's up to date on all US taxes but he's never done Canadian taxes. If he were to do his Canadian taxes, would he owe (he's never made money in Canada) and would he be able to apply for GSTS and the trillium? If so, how far back could he go to claim?

Answer (score 3):

If he is a Status Indian (legal term used, with apologies for use of the word) then he needs to get in touch with his band council for advice.   There are many different treaties, and they all have different tax exemption rules.

Answer (score 0):

Your boyfriend must report all income from the U.S. to the Canada Revenue Agency, and must do so in Canadian currency. This is because he lives in Canada. If he has failed to report this for tax years prior to 2018, it is time to hire a tax attorney immediately, as there are pretty serious consequences here.

There's a good chance your boyfriend should have been paying taxes in Canada instead of in the U.S., and using the reciprocal tax agreement between the two nations to avoid paying U.S. tax. If he's been paying tax in the U.S., you may need a tax specialist to help file a correction, to recover that money (as it is probably owed to Canada rather than the U.S.)

You have not provided enough information to determine if he'll owe taxes in Canada, but there's a very strong possibility. Again, if he owes for tax years prior to 2017, there will be additional fees and possible charges for failing to file.

I cannot stress this enough. If your boyfriend has failed to report this for tax years prior to 2018, he needs to stop what he's doing and immediately search out a tax attorney.

[This site](https://www.mileiq.com/en-ca/blog/tax-tips-canadians-work-us-companies-canada/) provided useful information which I have incorporated above.

Comment: While this is correct in general, his status as an Indian complicates matters, at least if he lives on a reserve.